# How can I move elements around in a multidimentional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and I need to modify it. Below you can see that each element in my array have multiple elements and some of them are also arrays.

```
Array
(
    [ordered] => Array
        (
            [label] => Order ordered                    
            [next_states] => Array
                (
                    [deliver] => Array
                        (
                            [target] => delivered
                        )    
                )    
            [status] => complete
        )

[delivered] => Array
    (
        [label] => Order delivered                    
        [next_states] => Array
            (
                [check_invoice] => Array
                    (
                        [target] => invoice_correct
                    )    
            )    
        [status] => complete
    )

[invoice_paid] => Array
    (
        [label] => Invoice paid                    
        [next_states] => 
        [status] => disabled
    )    
)
```

What I need to do is to take the element `[next_states]` from each element from my main array and add it to the next element. Actually, I only need the `keys` inside `[next_states]` and add it to a new key (`[next_step]`) in the next element from the entire whole array.

Example;

```
Array
(
    [ordered] => Array
        (
            [label] => Order ordered                    
            [next_states] => Array
                (
                    [deliver] => Array
                        (
                            [target] => delivered
                        )    
                )    
            [status] => complete
            [next_step] =>    //This first one can remain empty because it's the first one.
    )

[delivered] => Array
    (
        [label] => Order delivered                    
        [next_states] => Array
            (
                [check_invoice] => Array
                    (
                        [target] => invoice_correct
                    )    
            )    
        [status] => complete
        [next_step] => deliver  // <- HERE
    )

[invoice_paid] => Array
    (
        [label] => Invoice paid                    
        [next_states] => 
        [status] => disabled
        [next_step] => check_invoice  // <- HERE
    )    
)
```

I hope my question is clear enough, and that somebody will help me. I already have a foreach loop where I add the `[status]` to each element;

```
foreach ($steps as $key => $value) {
    $steps[$key]['next_step'] = prev($steps);
    if ($key === $nextStep) {
        $steps[$key]['status'] = 'active';
    } elseif (isset($uncompletedSteps[$key])) {
        $steps[$key]['status'] = 'disabled';
    } else {
        $steps[$key]['status'] = 'complete';
    }
}
```

I know I have to add something to the foreach loop mentioned above, but I simply don't know how to do this. Can somebody please show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use array_keys to create array used to find position in main array:

```
$keys = array_keys($step);
// Test that array has more than one element
if (($klen = count($keys)) < 2 ) die("illegal lenth of the array");

for($i = 0; $i < $klen-1; $i++) 
    // Test that current element has next_states key
    // and it points to array
    if(isset($steps[$keys[$i]]['next_states']) && is_array($steps[$keys[$i]]['next_states']))
        // Put key in next element
        $steps[$keys[$i+1]]['next_step'] = key($steps[$keys[$i]]['next_states']);
```

Comment: Glad that could help. Good luck!